# How to display two NSArray objects as sections of UITableview using NSDictionary in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsarray, nsdictionary

Here is my code 
ViewController.m

```
{
    NSArray *sectionTitleArray;

}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tablevw;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _tablevw.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    _tablevw.delegate = self;
    _tablevw.dataSource = self;

    sectionTitleArray = @[ @{ @"description": @"About Step0ne",
                              @"About Stepone": @[ @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 1" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 2" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 3" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 4" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 5" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 6" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 7" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 8" },
                                              ]
                              },
                           @{ @"description": @"Profile",
                              @"profile": @[ @{ @"text": @"profile 1" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 2" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 3" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 4" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 5" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 6" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 7" },
                                              @{ @"text": @"profile 8" },
                                              ]
                              },

                              ];
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {

        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"About Stepone"];
    cell.textLabel.text = [[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section]objectForKey:@"Profile"];

    return cell;
}
```

`About Stepone` and `Profile` are the two sections of my `tableview`. Whereas `stepone1`,`stepone2`,....`stepone8` should be my rows of About `Stepone` section .

Comment: you have to implement numberofSection delegate method.in that return yourArry.count. and to add section title you have to add header to each section from the delegate method. i.e. viewforheaderinsection.

Comment: yes, i added still am not getting any help

Comment: - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return sectionTitleArray.count;

}

Comment: - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
      UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280,40)];
    sectionView.tag=section;
    UILabel *viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(13, 0, _tablevw.frame.size.width-10, 40)];
    viewLabel.text=[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];
    NSDictionary *sectionData = [sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];
      viewLabel.text = [sectionData objectForKey:@"description"];
    [sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];
      return sectionView;
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is some tried and tested code for you. **I have made some changes in your data structure for the purpose of ease**. Hope you find that helpful.

```
{
    NSDictionary *_objects;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    _objects = @{@"About Stepone": @[ @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 1" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 2" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 3" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 4" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 5" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 6" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 7" },
                                      @{ @"text": @"Step0ne 8" }],
                 @"profile": @[ @{ @"text": @"profile 1" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 2" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 3" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 4" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 5" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 6" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 7" },
                                @{ @"text": @"profile 8" }]
                 };

}


- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table View

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return _objects.allKeys.count;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return ((NSArray *) _objects[_objects.allKeys[section]]).count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *object = _objects[_objects.allKeys[indexPath.section]][indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = object[@"text"];
    return cell;
}

- (NSString *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return _objects.allKeys[section];
}
```

Happy Coding.

Output is like:

[image: Output of above lines]

Comment: I implemented our code in mine.Am getting error as allkeys  not found on object of type NSArray.I declared as @property   NSArray *allKeys;

Comment: Please check that I have update your data structure a little for ease. I have made line (specifying that) bold in answer.

Comment: Yes,i used your updated data structure only.Please can you suggest where you have declared allkeys in the code sir.

Comment: The `_objects ` here is a `NSDictionary` (as you can see by it's declaration). And `allkeys ` is `NSDictionary`'s property. I have again edited answer to make it more clear.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100106/discussion-between-srinitha-and-rptwsthi).

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
   - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
          return 2 ;
     }

     - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
          if (section==0)
          {
                 return [array1 count];
          }
          else{
                 return [array2 count];
          }
     }

     - (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
          if(section == 0)
               return @"Section 1";
          else
               return @"Section 2";
     }


     - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
    {

          static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

          UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
         if (cell == nil) {
          cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
          }

     if (indexPath.section==0) {
         ObjectData *theCellData = [array1 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
         cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
     }
     else {
         ObjectData *theCellData = [array2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
         NSString *cellValue =theCellData.category;
         cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;
     }
         return cell;
```

Answer (score 0):

To add more than one section to the Table View, use delegate method  `numberOfSectionsInTableView`.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}
```

And to show particular number of rows use this delegate:

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict = [sectionTitleArray ObjectAtIndex:section]
    NSString *strSection = [[dict allKeys] objectAtIndex:2];
    NSArray *rows= [dict ObjectForKey:strSection];
    return rows.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think u missed this line of code..

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this by Following code:

For section number you have to return array's count in **numberOfSectionsInTableView** Delegate method.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
    return sectionTitleArray.count;// Total number of sections in the tableview.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Implement below delegate methods

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{

    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];

    return dict[@"description"];
}
```

You need to return the number of rows as below not 1

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section];

    NSArray *array=dict[dict[@"description"]];

    return array.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return sectionTitleArray.count;
}

--before your returning change both key names as same.
like for exampel profile and stepone should be same key

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [[[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:section]valueForKey:@"About Stepone"]count];
}
```